# I am getting an unexpected error when trying to write a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I get the following message when I try to save this code from the script editor on Google Sheets: "We're sorry, an unexpected error occurred during compilation."  The code creates a class with a method.

If it doesn't create a method I don't get the error, but the point of the object is the method.  I did this in the past in another Sheets application, but I can't even get it to work for a simple example.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // curr active spreadsheet
  var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();              // current active sheet
  var aLogger = tLogger(theSheet, 5, 1, 5);        // set up a logger

  aLogger.tLog("A test line: 1");
}

// object to do logging on a sheet
function tLogger(ourSheet, startLine, startCol, logLength) {

  // object properties:
  this.curline = startLine;
  this.sheetRef = ourSheet;
  this.theColumn = startCol;
  this.maxLog = startLine + logLength;

  ourSheet.getRange(startLine, startCol, logLength, 1).clear();  // clear old

  // including this is what causes the error:
  function this.tLog(tText) {  // log an entry on the sheet
    this.sheetRef.getRange(this.curline++, this.theColumn).setValue(tText);
    return;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `this` can be part of a valid function name.

Comment: Aha, although it indeed can be part of the name.  However, the correct syntax is thus:   this.tlog = function(tText) {}

Comment: @Matt McKrell Can you update your question by reflecting the modification of the comment? After the modification, in your script, how about creating the instance? So how about modifying from ``var aLogger = tLogger(theSheet, 5, 1, 5);`` to ``var aLogger = new tLogger(theSheet, 5, 1, 5);``?

Answer (score 0):

Re-code it with ES6 something like above

```
class tLogger {
  constructor(ourSheet, startLine, startCol, logLength) {
    this.curline = startLine;
    this.sheetRef = ourSheet;
    this.theColumn = startCol;
    this.maxLog = startLine + logLength;
  }
}
```